# Loading bundle.js failed in react-app. The app doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have started learning react recently. I am trying to make a stop watch and following is the code.

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react'

class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
        };

        this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
        this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this)
        this.changingTime = this.changingTime.bind(this)
    }

    startTimer() {
        let d = new Date();
        let startMin = d.getMinutes();
        let startSec = d.getSeconds();
        this.myVar = setInterval(this.changingTime(startMin, startSec), 1000)
    }

    changingTime(min, sec) {
        let date = new Date();
        this.setState({
            minutes: date.getMinutes() - min,
            seconds: date.getSeconds() - sec
        })
    }

    stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(this.myVar);
    }

    render() {
        return(<div><p> I am timer </p>
            <
            Timing minutes = {
                this.state.minutes
            }
            seconds = {
                this.state.seconds
            }
            /> <
            p > minutes < /p>
            <
            button onClick = {
                this.startTimer
            } > Start < /button> <
            button onClick = {
                this.stopTimer
            } > Stop < /button> < /
            div >
        );
    }
}

class Timing extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            h6 > {
                this.props.minutes
            }: {
                this.props.seconds
            } <
            /h6>
        );
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

I have added `<Timer/>` in App.js . I have created the app using create-react-app. The page loads and shows what it needs to show on load. But the stopwatch doesn't work as expected.

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oZ2A.png). As you can see, the page loads properly but doesn't work thereafter. The console shows bundle.js load fail error. But I am unable to understand if that is the cause of improper working or is my code faulty.

Comment: Can you share the webpack configuration file?

Comment: I created the app with create-react-app module. I didn't use webpack at all. So, I don't know if there is really any webpack configuration file. Please specify the location of config file if it would be present even in my scenario.